# Matching strings between lists and removing said string

Tags: python

I have a few lists here. A default list which will never change, a temporary list which is the target for this code to change, and two other lists.

I need to check both list2 and list3 (one at a time) for it's string contents, and then remove matched strings from list1temp. List1 is used for restoring the original strings to list1temp.

To be quite honest, I am very new and I have an idea of how to approach this, but I am not sure how to even attempt.

I am assuming I will need a for loop, and then use pop and append method.

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list1temp = ["a", "b", "c," "d"]

list2 = ["b", "c"]
list3 =  ["a"]  #<- this is still a list even though it has just one element because in the future it could be given more elements
```

I am struggling to match them

Comment: First of all, none of those are lists. `list1`, `list1temp`, and `list2` are tuples, which are like lists but are inmutable, this is, they can no tbe changed. `list3` is a string. Add `[` and `]` around the elements to make them lists.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. _then remove matched strings from list1temp_, this would mean that `list2` and `list3` would be empty eventually since `list1temp` contains all the letters

Comment: So what would be your expected output?

Comment: @Erfan I think he means to remove the elements that are found in list2 and list3 from list1temp, outputting `["d"]`.

Comment: @Adirio Ah, ok. This is my first mistake. Thank you. I will correct  that.

Comment: @Erfan I did not think about that. I do not actually want to empty the contents of list2 or list3, rather I just want to get the strings from inside them and remove them from list1temp.

Comment: @Sotos The expected output for the first loop should be `list1temp = ['a', 'd'], then list1temp contents should be restored with list1, and then loop back to list3, of which the second output will be list1temp = ['b', 'c', 'd']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions allow you to copy other lists filtering meanwhile.

1. `s not in list2` will return `true` if the element `s` is not in the `list2`.
2. `[s for s in list1 if condition]` will create a new list with the elements of `list1` that matches the condition, in our case the condition is not being in `list2` or `list3`.

```py
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

list2 = ["b", "c"]
list3 = ["a"]

list1temp = [s for s in list1 if s not in list2]
print(list1temp)
list1temp = [s for s in list1 if s not in list3]
print(list1temp)
```

Comment: Or just check if it's not in both list combined `list1temp = [s for s in list1 if s not in list2 + list3]`

Comment: That would also be valid but I would have to explain that adding two lists creates a new one with the elements concatenated. If we would like to go that way probably making `list2` and `list3` sets would also be a good idea.

Comment: I was actually gonna say the same as far as just using a set as it just makes sense

Comment: His comment points toward doing the filters separately so easier now.

Comment: t h a n k y o u

Answer (score 0):

You can also use set operations in python (and convert back the result to list):

```
list1temp = list(set(list1temp)-set(list2)-set(list3))
```

Comment: t h a n k  y o u

Comment: Ank you would lose ordering as sets are unordered. And he seems to need each filter by itself not both at the same time

Comment: @Adirio Filtering one by one can be done here also by doing the subtractions one by one on seperate lines. And if ordering matters to OP, I agree that would not be same.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach would be to iterate through each item in `list2` and `list3`, check if the item is in `list1temp`, and remove it from `list1temp` if that is the case.

Example:

```
for val in list2:
    if val in list1temp:
        list1temp.remove(val)

for val in list3:
    if val in list1temp:
        list1temp.remove(val)
```

You could also change the order of the loop above: iterate over the elements of `list1temp` then check if the items in list2 and list3 are there and remove them:

```
for val in list1temp:
    if val in list2 or val in list3:
        list1temp.remove(val)
```

NOTE: The methods above do not account for duplicate values in list1temp. In order to handle this case, you can keep retrying the check of "is this in the list" until it is false.

Example:

```
for val in list1temp:
    while val in list2 or val in list3:
        list1temp.remove(val)
```

The above approach used is not very efficient. The time complexity is O(m*n), where m is the length of `list1temp` and n is the sum of the lengths of `list2` and `list3`. (The `in` operator is O(n) on a list object).

For larger lists, a better solution would be to sort each list (could be done in O(n*log(n))), then make a single pass through the lists to check for matching values.

Example:

```
def list_remover(list1temp, list2, list3):
  2     #This runs in O(n*log(n))
  3     list1temp.sort()
  4     list2.sort()
  5     list3.sort()
  6
  7     #This runs in O(n)
  8     idx1 = 0
  9     idx2 = 0
 10     idx3 = 0
 11
 12     if len(list2) == 0:
 13         list2 = [list1temp[0] - 1]
 14     if len(list3) == 0:
 15         list3 = [list1temp[0] - 1]
 16
 17     while idx1 < len(list1temp):
 18         if list1temp[idx1] == list2[idx2]:
 19             list1temp.remove(list2[idx2])
 20         elif list1temp[idx1] == list3[idx3]:
 21             list1temp.remove(list3[idx3])
 22         elif list1temp[idx1] > list2[idx2] and idx2 < len(list2) - 1:
 23             idx2 += 1
 24         elif list1temp[idx1] > list3[idx3] and idx3 < len(list3) - 1:
 25             idx3 += 1
 26         else:
 27             idx1 += 1
 28     return list1temp
```

The code above also handles duplicates.

For more information about time complexity, read here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html

Comment: Wow. I appreciate you explaining all this. I must admit, it's a bit advanced and I don't understand alot of it. But I will certainly keep trying and keep this all in mind. t h a n k y o u